# A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

While running select count(*) from learning.CRIME_NON_PARTITION;, I am getting the exception below.

```
Application application_1512293830396_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1512293830396_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1512293830396_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client.
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client.
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Shell output: 1 file(s) moved.
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://Dell:8088/cluster/app/application_1512293830396_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

I am running hadoop on a windows machine (os- 8.1)

Comment: The error says what the problem is. Your permissions are not correct. Can you select from any table?

Comment: i did select on different table. but the same issue is repeating.